# Click notification that takes you to a particular class

Tags: android

What I have below is some notification code. What I would like to achieve with my notification code is when the notification is clicked, it will take the user to a particular class. Here is my notification code:

```
final int NOTIF_ID = 1234;   

     NotificationManager notifManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);   
     Notification note = new Notification(R.drawable.icon, "New Offers CLOSEBY!", System.currentTimeMillis());   

     PendingIntent intent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, new Intent(this, intentTHING.class), 0);   

     note.setLatestEventInfo(this, "You have 5 new offers", "Please CLICK THIS Notification to see what is avaliable!", intent);   

     notifManager.notify(NOTIF_ID, note);
```

I'm assuming that when the notification is clicked, this code here is supposed to take you to the declared class:

```
PendingIntent intent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, new Intent(this, intentTHING.class), 0);
```

However, it does not, the notification does appear, but I cannot see the class I have referenced in my code (i.e when clicked it does not take me to the class I want it to). I have the notification popup currently after a button has been pressed in another class. Once the user clicks on the notification it should push that screen and replace it with the intentTHING.class. Any ideas as to what I may be missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set pending Intent like this:

```
PendingIntent intent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, new Intent(this, intentTHING.class), 0);
note .contentIntent = intent;

note.setLatestEventInfo(this, "You have 5 new offers", "Please CLICK THIS Notification to see what is avaliable!", intent);   
notifManager.notify(NOTIF_ID, note);
```

Comment: Added that to the code but still it does not load the desired class.

Comment: have you added your activity in the manifest file...Plz check and I hope your class is the activity not the simple java class...

Comment: FFFFFUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUU I did, but I had a spelling mistake I had not previously seen. MASSIVE fail -_-

Comment: Yes thankyou I will select your answer as correct. I have to wait 2 minutes before I can, thankyou for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Am not sure but can try it out by doing this..

PendingIntent intent =
          PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,
          new Intent(this, intentTHING.class),  PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT | Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL);